# Clearing cookies, why is specific value required?

Tags: php, cookies

I am reading up on clearing cookies. Say a cookie is set with `setcookie("abc", "xyz", time()+3600)`, then from what I've read you unset it by using `setcookie("abc", "xyz", time()-3600)` which sets the cookie to expire in the past. All the examples I've seen use this format.

My question is why does the last parameter have to be specifically time()-3600, why can't it be time()-1 or time()-9999999 for example?

Comment: Any negative value will do, but this magic number `3600` just "feels right" for coders :)

Comment: @bsdnoobz I would think a number like 256 or 1048 or 65536 would "feel right" for a coder :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have to be `time() - 3600`. That's merely used in examples because it makes a nice tidy "one hour ago".  It just has to be some time *in the past*, so  `time()-1` or `time()-9999999` are acceptable as well, as is any value `< time()`.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why does the last parameter have to be specifically time()-3600, why can't it be time()-1 or time()-9999999 for example?

It doesn't. 3600 works, but anything in the past will work too.

Answer (score 1):

In `setcookie("abc", "xyz", time()-3600)` the trick is that this references the time on the server while the cookie expiration is dependent on the time of the host running the browser. If there is a mismatch of time between the two hosts, it is possible that it a cookie may not expire. However, using a time of ’1′ indicates an expiration time of 1 second after midnight, January 1st, 1970 which is the earliest possible expiration time.

Comment: The current timestamp won't be zero (well, not until the year 2038 problem kicks in on some devies). It can be any number below the current UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser reads a past time it is deleted

Answer (score -1):

`time()` Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

so when you do this `time() + or - somedigit` that means you are addiing or subtracting value to seconds,